# SQL Server 2008 Column Change Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, varchar, alter-table

I just recently took over a SQL Server database a number of tables, stored, procedures, triggers, etc. but I'm running into a slight problem.

Originally, a certain table consisted of three column: 
`id, description, foreign_key`

The description column was of type varchar(3000).
One of the developers found that 3000 characters wasn't enough so I ran an alter table command to update the column from varchar(3000) to varchar(5000).

The developer came to me claiming it didn't fix anything.  I tried to run a direct insert statement only to see a truncate error because the string I tried to explicitly insert into the description column was 3010 characters long.

The table definition says the column changed and I've tried rebooting the server to see if maybe there was something cached somewhere that could be causing it but nothing has worked so far.

If anyone has any ideas about why running the update command would work but the column would still have some kind of limitation please throw the info below.  We need to get this fixed at some point.  Thanks in advance for all the help everyone.

Comment: Have you checked that the column definition actually changed?  Are there any constraints that are checking for the length?  Are there any triggers that are putting the data into another column that is smaller?

Comment: What is the name of the table and the error message that you get?

Comment: Table name is irrelevant. I'm guessing the error message would be the ever helpful 'String or binary data would be truncated'. More useful would be to run SQL Profiler whilst trying the insert again and seeing what happens. That will reveal any triggers or other interference. Check constraints would make themselves known in the error message. Could also post the results of `SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName') AND name = 'ColumnName'`

Comment: I've checked everything from triggers to stored procedures and nothing is preventing the input length from being over 3000.  The table definition shows that the change took as well and the column is now updated to varchar(5000).  The recommended query results from the comment by Steve are as follows:

object_id = 762485795, 
name = description, 
column_id = 2, 
system_type_id = 167, 
user_type_id = 167, 
max_length = 5000, 
precision = 0, 
scale = 0, 
collation_name = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 
is_nullable = 1, 
is_ansi_padded = 1, 

and the rest of the columns are 0.

Comment: And just to be "that guy". Are you sure it's the right table? It's not one of those tables that have the same name in multiple schemas so you're looking at schema.table when it should be schema2.table?

Comment: Yes sir.  I've checked through all the other schemas and when writing the query to alter the table I made sure to declare what schema I was using as well to ensure it was the right table.